# Is it ok to ask for code review?

Tags: discussion, support, scope, site-recommendation

I have some nginx code that works, but I'd like some other eyes on it to make sure I didn't do something wrong. Is it ok to ask stackoverflow members to look at my configuration for bugs?

This question is in regards to the etiquette of asking questions within the stackoverflow community.

Comment: There's an entire site dedicated to this: [CodeReview.SE]. But make sure to meet their quality standards on questions as well.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Slow down.  Before you head over to Code Review, be sure that your question is on-topic there.  If it isn't, it'll be closed in fairly short order.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) lists pro: "Correctness in unanticipated cases" but con: "Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets". So I guess It Depends.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the question that someone has linked. Read them both, my question is about etiquette within the Stackoverflow communities (I didn't even know there was a code review site), the other question is asking if questions on the code review site should be closed while that site is in beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an entire site dedicated to this: Code Review. But make sure to meet their quality standards on questions as well.  <sup>([comment as answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295710/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-code-review/295714#comment200814_295710))</sup>